# transitive aliases on new index are not updated

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a index template

```
  "template": "index-monthly-1-*",
  "aliases": {
   "index-complete-1": {}
   }
```

and an aliases defined as

```
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "indices" : ["index-complete-1", "index-complete-2", "index-complete-3"], "alias" : "global-index" } }
    ]
}
```

When a new index "index-monthly-1" is created, the alias "global-index" is not updated, whereas the index "index-complete-1" is complete.

Is there a way to also update "global-index" on index creation? Do I have to specify "global-index" also in the template?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690083/elasticsearch-alias-auto-update-for-rolling-index

Comment: This may be helpful as well: https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-time-based-indices-efficiently

Comment: the linked questions doesn't include the transitive dependency that I have in the above example. I have : index -> alias -> alias, the example only has index -> alias.